# smbclient how get specific files

Tags: linux, smbclient

I have Synology NAS with embedded Linux and can use only predifined utilities.

When im try copy remote files through:

smbclient connect to remote

```
smb: \> prompt
smb: \> mask *file*.rar
smb: \> mput *
```

Copy is OK

but how i can do this?

smbclient connect to remote

```
smb: \> prompt
smb: \> mask "date ‘+%Y_%m_%d’*.rar" > I get error 
smb: \> mput *
```

I try use alias too, it don't work for me

Hope on your answers

Comment: smbclient doesn't know what to do with backticks. It's unix shell feature, not smbclient feature. If you are going to use it in a script, you can craft the filename with embedded date (or whatever) in a shell and feed smbclient with already built command, and there you can use backticks. See for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698694/smb-client-commands-through-shell-script